# Como passar múltiplos campos no endpoint de subscription da API do Azure Devops?

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-azure

Boa noite. Preciso criar uma assinatura via API da Azure Devops para que o webhook me envie atualizações do work item do board. Porém, preciso limitar o webhook para que a notificação seja disparada apenas se dois dos diversos campos forem atualizados. Aparentemente, só consigo limitar um campo por vez, na propriedade "changedFields" e nesse caso, eu teria que criar duas assinaturas (dois webhooks pra cada campo). A documentação, entretanto, diz que é possível fazer isso através de um payload personalizado pela API. Qual seria esse payload? É possível limitar por N campos?

Segue a documentação de referência:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#workitem.updated

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=7.0

{

  "publisherId": "tfs",

  "eventType": "workitem.updated",

  "resourceVersion": "5.1-preview.3",

  "consumerId": "webHooks",

  "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",

  "publisherInputs": {

    "projectId": "bbc3a709-3632-4e7a-a156-2ade50f19f36",

    "workItemType": "Task",

    "changedFields": "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" (COMO ENVIAR MAIS DE UM CAMPO?!)

  },

  "consumerInputs": {

    "url": "https://...."

  }

}
```

Comment: como está no plural "changedFields" é esperado que aceite uma lista, já tentou campos separados por vírgul ou ponto-e-vírgula? ou ainda passar um array? (ex `changedFiles: [ "campo1", "campo2" ]`) na documentação não tem exemplos claros para essa propriedade

Comment: @RicardoPontual já testei destas 3 formas, nenhuma deu certo